# Which program to use for viewing mulitplex jpg and mp4 360x360 photosphere files?

Tags: default-programs, file-format, video-player, image-viewers

TL;DR - Which program to use for viewing mulitplex jpg and mp4 360x360 photosphere files?

Bublcam provides http://www.bublcam.com/products/bublcam Photosphere Videos and Photos in Multiplex format as raw, and eventually you can download processed Equirectangular.

I would be really interested in ability to view **projected** (you know, play, look around like on streeview etc.) raw mp4 and jpg files in multiplexed format, i.e. from four cameras.

Example how multiplexed look like:
[image: Example of multiplex bublcam image]
http://techcrunch.com/2013/11/05/bublcam/multiplex_bubl2/

Answer (score 2):

[FSPViewer](http://www.fsoft.it/FSPViewer/download/) is a free viewer for spherical panoramic images, very simple, but fast even with large HiRes files.

Comment: Nice first answer! Still, I don't see support for video, but good start with static images.